# Testing for an item in lists - Python 3

Tags: list, python-3.x

As part of a school project we are creating a trouble shooting program. I have come across a problem that I cannot solve:

```
begin=['physical','Physical','Software','software',]
answer=input()
if answer in begin[2:3]:
    print("k")
    software()
if answer in begin[0:1]:
    print("hmm")
    physical()
```

When I try to input software/Software no output is created. Can anybody see a hole in my code as it is?

Comment: I see many holes, What's your input? Provide a sample input and expected output. See What is a [mcve].

Comment: When I try to input software/Software

Comment: Also the input is assigned to answer

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: 'k' its just a placeholder for now

Comment: Why are you using a list for this? A dictionary would seem a much more natural structure, you could store the functions you're calling in it directly: `functions = {'physical': physical, 'software': software}`, then use `functions[answer.lower()]()`.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, slice end values are **exclusive**. You are slicing a smaller list than you think you are:

```
>>> begin=['physical','Physical','Software','software',]
>>> begin[2:3]
['Software']
>>> begin[0:1]
['physical']
```

Use `begin[2:4]` and `begin[0:2]` or even `begin[2:]` and `begin[:2]` to get all elements from the 3rd to the end, and from the start until the 2nd (inclusive):

```
>>> begin[2:]
['Software', 'software']
>>> begin[2:4]
['Software', 'software']
>>> begin[:2]
['physical', 'Physical']
>>> begin[0:2]
['physical', 'Physical']
```

Better yet, use `str.lower()` to limit the number of inputs you need to provide:

```
if answer.lower() == 'software':
```

With only one string to test, you can now put your functions in a dictionary; this gives you the option to list the various valid answers too:

```
options = {'software': software, 'physical': physical}

while True:
    answer = input('Please enter one of the following options: {}\n'.format(
        ', '.join(options))
    answer = answer.lower()
    if answer in options:
        options[answer]()
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, {} is not a valid option, try again".format(answer))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list slicing is wrong, Try the following script.

```
begin=['physical','Physical','Software','software',]
answer=input()
if answer in begin[2:4]:
    print("k")
    software()
if answer in begin[0:2]:
    print("hmm")
    physical()
```